# wrap up a block of code to a compile-time value

Tags: c++, vector, compilation

I tried to create a vector with a reserve capacity at compile-time.
C++ seems not to be smart to prevent me from doing this

```cpp
// global scope
constexpr auto vec = []() -> std::vector<uint16_t> {
    auto vec = std::vector<uint16_t>();
    vec.reserve(9);
    return vec;
}();

int main() {
    ...
}
```

`error:` the type 'const std::vector' of 'constexpr' variable 'vec' is not literal

Thank you!

Comment: This is not possible in C++. What problem are you trying to solve. No, not the one about creating a "vector with a reserve capacity at compile-time"; but the problem to which the solution you think involves creating a "a vector with a reserve capacity at compile-time", and that's what you're asking about.

Comment: If you make vector a `constexpr` you can make it a `std::array` as well. If you need to resize it later, then `constexpr` doesn't help much. Also, why do you think compiler doesn't prealloacte 9 slots? Maybe it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`constexpr` tells that the function can be evaluated at compile time. The returned object cannot change after that. So qualifying a vector `constexpr` kills it's purpose. It is supposed to be dynamic structure. If you `constexpr` it you could use simple `array` instead.

It's seems you don't want to have a `constexpr` vector, but one with preallocated space. You should check your compiler for this. E.g. new **gcc is smart enough to merge `reserve` into initial allocation**, at least for `int` type:

The following with -O2 (https://godbolt.org/z/BKE28g):

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> f() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(11);
}
```

Produces:

```
f():
    mov     edi, 44
    sub     rsp, 8
    call    operator new(unsigned long)
    mov     rdi, rax
    call    operator delete(void*)
```

`44` is no coincidence. It's `11*sizeof(int)`. You can throw in in a return statement which complicates the output but there is still one `operator new()` with appropriate size.